# В unity при использовании SetParent() объект меняет свою форму на родительскую

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            Vector3 point = new Vector3(camera.pixelWidth/2, camera.pixelHeight/2, 0);
            Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(point);   
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                hit.transform.SetParent(ctrl_element.transform, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Когда луч попадает в объект это объект должен стать дочерним другого объекта, но при этом он исчезает (мы предполагаем, что он меняет форму на родительскую, так как родительский объект - это пустой объект).

Comment: Если объект становится дочерним к другому, у него просто изменяются позиция, размер и поворот - относительно родительского. Объект не может стать пустым объектом, если стал дочерним к пустому. К тому же, что значит `он исчезает`? Вы в инспекторе можете спокойно посмотреть все параметры объекта, его позицию, а при двойном клике на него в иерархии, вас к нему перенесет.

Comment: `мы предполагаем`... а посмотреть на него в редакторе не проще, что с ним, где он, чем фигнёй страдать?

Answer (score 1):

У SetParent(Transform) есть перегрузка SetParent(Transform parent, bool worldStays). Используйте перегрузку чтобы исключить ваши проблемы.

> worldPositionStays    If true, the parent-relative position, scale and rotation are modified such that the object keeps the same world space position, rotation and scale as before.

Если ваш будущий родительский объект `ctrl_element` выключен, то все дочерние объекты будут выключены, по этому убедитесь, что он включен в момент изменения объекту родителя `hit.transform.SetParent(ctrl_element.transform, true);`

Так же вам стоит проверить, есть ли влияние на `ctrl_element` из других источников, возможно он выключается или перемещается по клику, а может он удаляется?